# In coding part, if else condition 'else' is not working while writing results in excel using selenium webdriver [API Automation]

Tags: java, excel

> > Any one please clarify how to resolve this issue.
> > I am running following code to write a output in excel sheet using Excl utils,

```
public class AdditionalStorage_Get extends RESTAssuredBase{
    //For Reporting 
    @BeforeTest// - > 2
    public void setValues() {

        testCaseName = "Validate additionStorage Page Api";
        testDescription = "Verify additionStorage - Get request";
        nodes = "subscription/additionStorageRequest/f1c547a5-4520-11eb-9a4d-8ea21db6e23d";
        category = "REST";
        dataFileName = "";
        dataFileType = "JSON";
        SheetName="APITest";
        Expected= "Additional Storage detail should be displayed";
    }
    @Test
    public void additionStorage() throws IOException {      


        // Post the request
        Response response = get("subscription/additionStorageRequest/f1c547a5-4520-11eb-9a4d-8ea21db6e23d");

        // Verify the Content type
        verifyContentType(response, "JSON");

        // Verify the response status code
        verifyResponseCode(response, 200);  
        int status = response.statusCode();

        //Verify the response time 
        verifyResponseTime(response, 2000);
        long time = response.time();

        enableResponseLog(response);
        if(status == 200)

        {
            Actual = "Request Additional Storage detail is displayed correctly";
            ExcelUtils.updateTestResult(SheetName, testDescription, status, time, Actual, Expected, "pass");
        }

        else

        {
            Actual="The Response is Not expected";
            ExcelUtils.updateTestResult(SheetName, testDescription, status, time, Actual, Expected, "Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

> > Here I am passing my excel sheet to write, While running above script

> > Its Showing error as "java.lang.NullPointerException" at lib.utils.ExcelUtils.updateTestResult(ExcelUtils.java:40)

```
public class ExcelUtils extends RESTAssuredBase{

    public static void updateTestResult(String SheetName, String testDescription,int code,
            Long time,String Actual,String Expected,String Result) throws IOException {

        DateTimeFormatter date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy"); 
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("./reports/ExcelReport.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(SheetName);
        int totalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 13;


        try {
            for (int i = 1; i < totalRow; i++) 
            {
                XSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(i);
                String ce = r.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();  
                if (ce.contains(testDescription))
                {
                    r.createCell(2).setCellValue(code);
                    r.createCell(3).setCellValue(time);
                    r.createCell(4).setCellValue(Actual);
                    r.createCell(5).setCellValue(Expected);
                    r.createCell(6).setCellValue(Result);
                    file.close();
                    System.out.println("result updated");
                }

            }
            //file.close();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("./reports/ExcelReport.xlsx"),false);
        workbook.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you point out the line:40 that actually throws NullPointerException? is it the commented out file.close?

Comment: Getting error on this line - String ce = r.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

Comment: Yes file.close is commented

Comment: My best bet is, that ./reports/ExcelReport.xlsx is empty => workbook is empty => r.getCell(1) produces Nullpointer

Comment: I have to write excel at 13th line. 

Have initiated  reader as 
int totalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 13; 
So I thing Its assuming cell 1 as empty how to recyify it.